# ADB command to restore application data with Titanium backup?

Tags: backup, restore, titanium-backup

I made backup with Titanium backup. Is there a way to restore application data using adb commands? Couldn't find solution to this, recently started learning about android 
I tried with this but no luck.

```
adb -s MYDEVICE shell am start -t "file:///sdcard/backup/org.mozilla.firefox.TiBkp"  -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup

Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent
```

I want to use adb to start Titanium backup and command it to restore that one app settings backup, possibly withount confirmation. 
But if there is some other solution to restore one app settings using command line withount confirmation it will be useful.

Backup file "org.mozilla.firefox.TiBkp" is backup of settings for Mozilla made with TB. It has `.TiBkp` extension but I also have `.gz` backup also made with TB.
Backup file is in the sdcard, but if there is solution to restore it from C: it will be useful as well. Only I don't want to restore entire phone, nor .apk itself, only settings for one app.
Also I tried with 
`adb restore` with different commands and options but it initiates full backup and ask me to confirm.

Comment: May I ask why you can't just use the Titanium Backup app to restore app data?

Comment: I need to apply it in a script.

Comment: Did you get it working? I just got a device where `adb restore` is broken, so I'd appreciate a TiBu CLI. Besides: `adb restore` always restores all that's in the file passed. If you want "single apps", you must do so at backup time.